# How to integrate CRM contact data to HTML page web resource in Dynamics CRM 2011?

Tags: html, dynamics-crm-2011, integration, crm

Can i integrate CRM contact data to HTML page web resource?

i got following link.

http://dynamicscrminfo.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-integrate-crm-contact-data-based.html

but there what is utils/FetchUtil.js file.where can i get?

Comment: try to contact the author of the post: https://plus.google.com/114063211362037629256/posts

Answer (score 0):

The way the author of that post is using the CRM Data in a WebResource is explained with extension in the SDK.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=24004

You just need to use the SOAP or REST Endpoint to get the data and then is just a normal HTML website. You have plenty of examples in the SDK of JS and HTML.

Later you can use that HTML in any form.

Can you please specify what is your original requirement?? Or you just want to put CRM data into an HTML website? Is that website going to be in any CRM Form, I assume that because you are talking about a webresource.

Thanks,

Mario